# Android - Coordinator Layout, Drawer Layout and Fragments

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I have spent some time trying to implement this, and did my fair bit of research but couldn't make it work. 
In the [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) example by Chris Banes, he makes the toolbar scroll away when the ViewPager is scrolled. The ViewPager is included directly in his drawer layout, just before the NaviagtionView.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- THIS CONTAINS COORDINATOR LAYOUT with APPBAR LAYOUT + VIEWPAGER -->
    <include layout="@layout/include_list_viewpager"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The include_list_viewpager file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I would like to have a FrameLayout (or NestedScrollView) instead of the ViewPager. Then, I could dynamically load fragments in it as the user clicks on the drawer layout items, and all of them would have a nice animated Toolbar. So far, I'm not able to make the Toolbar scroll away when operating in the invoked fragments. I wonder if it is at all possible.

Has anybody achieved this? Any pointer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us your layout include_list_viewpager

Comment: edited with the content of include_list_viewpager from the cheesesquare app

Answer (score 7):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tab_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

CoordinatorLayout must be the parent of all views. DrawerLayout gets the layout_behavior.  Since you want to interact with the elements of viewpager, it needs to be in the top view of the DrawerLayout.

Comment: for me this code is not working, i already added the missing CoordinatorLayout tag, but still my view within the AppBarLayout are doing nothing, standing there really steady. any ideas?